# Fetching the user profile failed when scanning qr code or publishing

Tags: android, react-native, command-line-interface, expo

I've started using Expo and installed the latest versions of node.js , git , jdk , expo and also expo on my mobile phone.
Everything is alright when running expo start but when I try to scan the Qr-code on my phone tells me "something went wrong could not load exp://myip:1900.network response timed out."
and also in browser Expo these messages
Fetching the user profile failed
connect ETIMEDOUT 35.202.142.166:443
Same Issue when trying to publish the app

I have my Firewall off,
Logged in from expo android app,
and in metro bundler shows logged in,
I also tried logging in from npm and same message.
I have changed my network priority and any suggested ways.
My pc is connected with ethernet cable and my phone on the wifi of same router,can this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to say is that Expo is not opening in my country , so I'm using it with a proxy 
and when I click view error log This appears:
Uncaught Error : java.io.IOException:Unexpected end of stream on connection {192.168.1.4:19000,proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=/192.168.1.4:19000 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1

No idea?